# While I am trying to add up one dictionary's values into the list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a data for my method as dictionary like this:

```
 data = {
  'Apple': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Pear',  'Banana','Banana', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Pear'],
  'Banana': ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Pear','Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana'],
  'Pear': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear','Pear', 'Apple', 'Pear']}
```

Key is the actual class that I want to classify correctly, the values are the predicted classes. I want to create a confusion matrix using this data's information.

```
def confusionMatrix(data):
    for key,value in data.iteritems():
        temp={'Apple':0,'Banana':0,'Pear':0}
        for i in value:
            temp[i]+=1
        print temp
        print temp[key]
        n=len(data)
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i==j:
                    print temp[key],
                else:
                    print 1,
            print
```

I want my print result as:

```
      Apple Banana Pear
 Apple  2    4      4
 Banana 3    5      2
 Pear   3    2      5
```

But somehow I couldn't manage I get their values separately and cannot sum mathematically.
If you would help me solve this problem, it will be super awesome and appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Why did you completely change your question?

Comment: This is not me writing, I guess my friend asked and deleted, I am really sorry, sir.

Comment: Wasting people's time is not cool.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
keys = sorted(data.keys())
print '{0:<10}'.format(''),
for k in keys:
    print '{0:<10}'.format(k),
print
for k in keys:
    print '{0:<10}'.format(k),
    for l in keys:
        print '{0:<10}'.format(data[k].count(l)), 
    print

#            Apple      Banana     Pear      
# Apple      2          4          4         
# Banana     2          5          3         
# Pear       3          2          5
```

where I used the list's `count` method to get the counts.

Answer (score 0):

You have a **dictionary** of **list**. Iterate over the dictionary and then over the list and collect in a pandas DataFrame and apply a crosstab.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pandas.DataFrame([
    [col1,col2] for col1, value1 in data.items() for col2 in value1
])

pd.crosstab(df.ix[:,0],df.ix[:,1])
```